# Don't know how to make search form in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, search, ruby-1.9

I need a search form in my rails 3.2.3 application, but i don't know how to do this, yesterday i had it fixed but then i deleted it :(.

Here are my Controller and Model:

Controller

```
class BedrijfsgegevensController < ApplicationController   
  def index
    @bedrijfsgegevens = Bedrijfsgegeven.all
    @bedrijfsgegevens = Bedrijfsgegeven.search(params[:search])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @bedrijfsgegevens }
    end
  end

  # GET /bedrijfsgegevens/1
  # GET /bedrijfsgegevens/1.json
  def show
    @bedrijfsgegeven = Bedrijfsgegeven.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @bedrijfsgegeven }
    end
  end

  # GET /bedrijfsgegevens/new
  # GET /bedrijfsgegevens/new.json
  def new
    @bedrijfsgegeven = Bedrijfsgegeven.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @bedrijfsgegeven }
    end
  end

  # GET /bedrijfsgegevens/1/edit
  def edit
    @bedrijfsgegeven = Bedrijfsgegeven.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /bedrijfsgegevens
  # POST /bedrijfsgegevens.json
  def create
    @bedrijfsgegeven = Bedrijfsgegeven.new(params[:bedrijfsgegeven])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @bedrijfsgegeven.save
        format.html { redirect_to @bedrijfsgegeven, notice: 'Bedrijfsgegeven was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @bedrijfsgegeven, status: :created, location: @bedrijfsgegeven }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @bedrijfsgegeven.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /bedrijfsgegevens/1
  # PUT /bedrijfsgegevens/1.json
  def update
    @bedrijfsgegeven = Bedrijfsgegeven.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @bedrijfsgegeven.update_attributes(params[:bedrijfsgegeven])
        format.html { redirect_to @bedrijfsgegeven, notice: 'Bedrijfsgegeven was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @bedrijfsgegeven.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /bedrijfsgegevens/1
  # DELETE /bedrijfsgegevens/1.json
  def destroy
    @bedrijfsgegeven = Bedrijfsgegeven.find(params[:id])
    @bedrijfsgegeven.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to bedrijfsgegevens_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
            end
        end
    end
```

Model

```
class Bedrijfsgegeven < ActiveRecord::Base

    def search
    @search = Bedrijfsgegeven.search() do
    keywords(params[:search])
    end
    end

    def self.search(search)
        if search
        find(:all, :conditions => ['Voornaam LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
    else
        find(:all)
    end
  end

    validates :voornaam, 
              :achternaam, 
              :woonplaats, 
              :telefoon, 
              :website, 
              :email, 
              :presence => true

  attr_accessible :achternaam, :email, :telefoon, :voornaam, :website, :woonplaats
end
```

i hope someone could help me out with this.

Grtz Kees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read / watched the following railscast:

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax

Helps me every time I need basic search

Comment: Likewise, Railscasts is a fantastic place to start though. Don't forget to mark my answer as 'answered' if it helps.

Comment: I have another question. Now i can search for only 1 value. in my model:

 def self.search(search)
  if search
  find(:all, :conditions => ['voornaam LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
 else
  find(:all)
 end
  end

The only thing i can search for is voornaam (firstname in english) how do i change that so i can search for al the records like voornaam, achternaam, woonplaats, telefoon, website, email?

thanks

Comment: Personally, I use thinking sphinx for advanced search. Faster and pretty easy to set up. You can read about it here: http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/

Comment: i Can't work with thinking sphinx because i'm using a Sql Server 2005 database. Sphinx only supports MYSQL and postgreSQL

Comment: Ok. Yuk ;) Not so familiar with how to deal with that as I jumped from basic search as above, to sphinx.

Comment: the most tutorials on the internet about useful search engines are very difficult to understand when your in the beginning of working with rails. I hope i can fix it with a nice and advanced search engine. anyways thanks for your help :)

Comment: No problem. If I find something suitable on my travels I'll send your way.

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend you to start using repositories which will make you safe from these incidental delete. You can get 5 free repositries at bitbucket.org. Both git and mercurial are awesome.

Comment: i don't understand what you mean. could you explain this?

Comment: You should start using git / mercurial to avoid this type of situation of accidental delete.

Comment: i have git installed, but i deleted it because it did not work in the beginning but later on it started working. but i deleted it though, don't know why.

Comment: i just understood your answer, in the beginning i was a little newbie starting with rails. but now i understand thanks.